# Check condition for No of days using Dataset values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `dataset` in which there is a column named as `No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending`

Now here what I want is, I have 2 conditions

*1. Send Mail to Users if( No of days is less than 5 days)*

*2. Send Mail to Seniors if( No of days is More than or equal to 5 days)*

Below is my screenshot of the dataset

[image: DS]

And what I tried is below

```
 if (dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString() >= 5)
                {
                    //send mail to senior
                }
                else
                {
                    // send mail to users
                }
```

But the above code is not working. Is there any way work around for this ??

**UPDATED**

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT", SqlConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString() == "5")
                {
                    //send mail to senior
                }
                else
                {
                    // send mail to users
                }
                    sbody = "Dear " + dr["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  " +

                    "The No of days the document pending with you is " + dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString() + " days. <br /><br /> " +

                    "Please login with the link <b>http://akruticity/psiterp/ </b> <br /><br /> " +

                    "<b>THIS IS A SYSTEM GENERATED MAIL. PLEASE DO NOT REPLY </b>";
            }
```

Comment: You are using dr[""] I assume that you are using a datareader ? Could you post complete code on how you read your dataset ?

Comment: You're comparing a string to a int it's never going to work, you need to cast it to a integer first. Maybe you could try `int.Parse(dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString()) >=5`

Comment: @toby: I know that's incorrect, what's the other way round for this ?

Comment: You have to tell us more about the problem, does it compile ? does it throw an exception ? What's the value of `dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"]` ? does it even enter the foreach loop ?

Comment: @toby: Yes, it enters loop for sure. And i get `dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString()` as **28** for first  row

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't get what the problem is, but if it's the condition then your answer is `if(int.Parse(dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString()) <5){//send mail to user} else {//send mail to Seniors}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117477/discussion-between-toby-and-n-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (int.parse(dr["No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending"].ToString()) >= 5)
      {
                //send mail to senior
      }
      else
      {
                // send mail to users
      }
```

Keep in mind that the order of the rows on client side (dataset) may not be the same as what you see in management studio.